# Why "Begin" and not "begins" in the phrase "Let the adventure begin"?

Tags: grammar, learning

Normally,  the phrase "The adventure begins" uses the third person version of the verb.

Why is it "Let the adventure begin"? It is because this is a special tense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the form is imperative + bare infinitive and not present simple. Same as in: “Let him go”. You wouldn’t say “Let him goes”. In both sentences, go and begin are bare infinitives, not 3rd person singular of present simple.

Furthermore the *adventure* is a subject in the example “The adventure begins”, but in the other one “Let the adventure begin” it is an object. This is easier to spot in the example I gave, where the object is *him*. The form in which a personal pronoun in the 3rd person singular masculine can be an object is “he”, so when you see the word *him* you know it can’t be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: It sounds a bit strange to say the "subject" in OP's "Let the adventure begin" is an implied ***you***, because *semantically* it's not normally the addressee who "allows" the adventure to start. But syntactically I guess that must be it, since it *is* an "imperative" construction.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. What I meant was that this probably caused the confusion in the first place (in the example "The adventure begins" adventure is the object, and in the other one it is not - one might think that adventure should be followed with the same verb form in any case). I'll edit and try to make it clearer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry, followed **by** the same verb form, I don't know what got into me...